# InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having trouble sending email from my app at Google App Engine. I am experiencing several newbee hurdles and I would appreciate your help.

I take this function from [the tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html) and for the "sender" field I put my gmail account that I used to create the app:

```
mail.send_mail(sender="owners_email_acco...@gmail.com", 
                       to="xxxx...@gmail.com", 
                       subject="test email from app", 
                       body="hello")
```

when I try this, I get the error:

```
InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender
```

But the email

```
sender="owners_email_acco...@gmail.com",
```

is the email I use to log into the app; this is the email I used to create the app.

The tutorial says:

`The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender address must be one of the following types: The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can add administrators to an application using the Administration Console.`

So the email I used to create the app should work as a sender. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

(I asked the [same question](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/87575a2d8722024c?hl=en#) in GAE group but there was no reply)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Appengine sending emails: \[Error\] unauthorized sender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621019/google-appengine-sending-emails-error-unauthorized-sender)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I read that aliases and nicknames through google apps won't be recognised as their underlying address so maybe that's the problem.
I approached this just a few days ago and after making sure all sender addresses were listed in the 'permissions' section of the application console, it all worked fine.

Comment: the sender address I use to send the email is exactly the same email that is listed in the Permissions section. I just doublechecked now. What are ``aliases and nicknames through google apps``? I am using the email as copied exactly from the Permissions in the dashboard. Thanks.