# Google Appengine sending emails: [Error] unauthorized sender

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I'm trying to use google app engine's mail service on my site.  It's showing some error whenever I visit the page that sends the email.  The error says that I am using an unauthorized sender for the message.  Here's the code that sends the email:

```
mail.send_mail(sender="myapp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
     to=input_dict["email"],
     subject="Mondays user activation",
     body=content)
```

When I try out the site locally (using `dev_appserver.py`) it doesn't show the error, but it doesn't send the email (Note: I have to add the `--enable_sendmail` option when I try it locally).  The error only shows up when I publish the site.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Very old thread but it solved my problem... just wanted to point out that your `input_dict` is a list :-P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What is myapp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com?  You might not be able to send mail from that address.

> App Engine applications can send email messages on behalf of the app's
> administrators, and on behalf of users with Google Accounts.
>
> The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender address
> must be one of the following types:
>
> - The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can add administrators to an application using the Administration
>   Console.
> - The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address
>   with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be
>   on a domain managed by Google Apps.
> - Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).
> - Any valid email receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com. Domain accounts are accounts outside of the
>   Google domain with email addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or
>   @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

Comment: Whoops!  I misunderstood what sending address I was supposed to use for my app.  `Service Account Name: myapp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com Use this name when interacting with external services on behalf of your application.` Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have tried with all mails they have mentioned, owner mail, gserviceaccount mail, mail account with app name still it is giving as unauthorised sender, thanks

Answer (score 11):

First follow these steps

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#who_can_send_mail

Then you need to manually add the sender email in cloud console

[How to add an authorized sender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqHD1.png)

Comment: This is the best answer, as you have to do both steps to be able to send mail from the server.

Answer (score 3):

You may also have to add the email address you which to send the email from to the App Engine application settings Email API authorized senders.

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail

Answer (score 2):

Add the unauthorized email address as an administrator here:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/permissions/projectpermissions